# Pthread. Round-robin. Не правильно замеряет время работы функции

Tags: c++, pthread

Задание состоит в реализации двух алгоритмов умножения полиномов.
Первый с помощью БПФ, второй - умножение столбиком. Оба алгоритма надо распараллелить и сравнить время их работы.

Вот умножение столбиком.

Само умножение.

```
double *bf_mult(complex<double> *a1, int n1, complex<double> *a2, int n2) {
auto l1 = int(ceil(log2(n1)));
auto l2 = int(ceil(log2(n2)));
int m = max(l1, l2);
auto n3 = int(pow(2, m + 1));
auto *result = new double[n3];
for (int i = 0; i < n3; i++) {
    result[i] = 0;
}

sched_param schedparam;
pthread_attr_t attr;
schedparam.sched_priority = 30;
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr, SCHED_OTHER);
pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &schedparam);
pthread_t thread_1_bf, thread_2_bf;

bf_data param;
param.n1 = n1;
param.n2 = n2;
param.a1 = a1;
param.a2 = a2;
param.result = result;

pthread_create(&thread_1_bf, &attr, bf_thread_1_body, (void *) &param);
pthread_create(&thread_2_bf, &attr, bf_thread_2_body, (void *) &param);
pthread_join(thread_1_bf, nullptr);
pthread_join(thread_2_bf, nullptr);
pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
return result;
```

}

Функция для первого потока.

```
void *bf_thread_1_body(void *param) {
auto *data = (bf_data *) param;
int n1 = data->n1;
int n2 = data->n2;
complex<double> *A1 = data->a1;
complex<double> *A2 = data->a2;
double *result = data->result;

for (int i = 0; i < n1; i += 2) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j += 2) {
        result[i + j] += A1[i].real() * A2[j].real();
    }
}
for (int i = 1; i < n1; i += 2) {
    for (int j = 1; j < n2; j += 2) {
        result[i + j] += A1[i].real() * A2[j].real();
    }
}
```

}

Функция для второго потока.

```
void *bf_thread_2_body(void *param) {
auto *data = (bf_data *) param;
int n1 = data->n1;
int n2 = data->n2;
complex<double> *A1 = data->a1;
complex<double> *A2 = data->a2;
double *result = data->result;

for (int i = 0; i < n1; i += 2) {
    for (int j = 1; j < n2; j += 2) {
        result[i + j] += A1[i].real() * A2[j].real();
    }
}
for (int i = 1; i < n1; i += 2) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j += 2) {
        result[i + j] += A1[i].real() * A2[j].real();
    }
}
```

}

Далее тестируем время работы двух алгоритмов таким образом.

```
void test(void) {
for (int k = 1; k < 128; k *= 2) {
    int n1 = 1024 * k;
    int n2 = 1024 * k;
    cout << "n1= " << n1 << " n2= " << n2 << endl;
    double *fft_res, *bf_res;
    auto *mass1 = new complex<double>[n1];
    auto *mass2 = new complex<double>[n2];
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        mass1[i] = (rand() % 10, 0);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
        mass2[i] = (rand() % 10, 0);
    }

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    fft_res = fft_mult(mass1, n1, mass2, n2);
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration<double, milli> time_span = t2 - t1;
    cout << "fft_mult time " << time_span.count() << " milliseconds." << endl;

    t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    bf_res = bf_mult(mass1, n1, mass2, n2);
    t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    time_span = t2 - t1;
    cout << "bf_mult time " << time_span.count() << " milliseconds." << endl;

    bool ok = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < n1 + n2; i++) {
        if (abs(fft_res[i] - bf_res[i]) > 0.1) {
            // cout << i << " " << fft_res[i] << " " << bf_res[i] << endl;
            ok = false;
        }
    }
    cout << "fft=bf " << ok << "\n" << endl;
    delete[]mass1;
    delete[]mass2;
    delete[]fft_res;
    delete[]bf_res;
}
```

}

Если в функции bf_mult выбрать планировщик SHED_OTHER,

```
pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr, SCHED_OTHER);
```

то получим такой результат.

[image: SHED_OTHER]

А если выбрать SHED_RR, то такой

[image: SHED_RR]

При выборе любого планировщика, кроме SHED_RR, показывает время около 6 сек, при n1=n2=65536.

Почему при выборе SHED_RR показывает время работы 0.6 мсек ?

Comment: Дело все в том что sched_rr имеет более высокий приоритет чем любой другой планировщик (кроме fifo). Но sched_rr имеет более менее хорошую политику в следствии чего так сложились лунные пространство ядра в следствии чего выполнение идет в порядки быстрей. Но тут стоит проверить тебе можно поиграть с настройками интервала времени выполнения кванта и ты можешь так же ухудшить совой результат. Я точно не помню как это сделать но я верю в тебя и ты сможешь нагуглить правильные функции)

Comment: То что shed_rr обычно быстрее я знаю.Но не в 10000 раз. У первого алгоритма сложность O(n*log(n)), у второго O(n^2). По первой картинке с shed_other это видно. В случае с shed_rr складывается ощущение, что t2 = high_resolution_clock::now(); не ждет завершения потоков, а срабатывает сразу.